# Convert strings in a list to a list of dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
mylist = ['{"data": {"id": "854652314"', '"value": 854652314', '"name": "854652314"}}', '{"data": {"id": "B2"', '"value": "B2"', '"name": "B2"}}', '{"data": {"id": "457856954"', '"value": 457856954', '"name": "457856954"}}']
```

I would like to convert strings to dictionary.

I've tried this code:

```
res = [json.loads(idx.replace("'", '"')) for idx in mylist]
print(res)
```

But I get an error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 28 (char 27)

May I know how to solve the error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: your list is extremely messed up. Please spend the necessary time fixing it. Ex: ` 854652314'`

Comment: the problem is in `.replace`

Comment: There are no single quotes in the strings, why are you replacing them?

Comment: Where did that list come from? Can't you fix how it's created?

Comment: How did the JSON objects get split across multiple list elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jsons = []
current = []
for i, m in enumerate(mylist):
    if m.startswith('{"data":') and i > 0:
        jsons.append(", ".join(current))
        current = [m]
    else:
        current.append(m)

jsons.append(", ".join(current))

data = [json.loads(j) for j in jsons]
```

Comment: lengthy solution :(

Comment: hahaha those are the best comments :) feel free to suggest another more concise and understandable by a beginner ;)

Comment: Sure but the problem is the list that was totally messed up in a wrong way..

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ... so? What does it matter if it is a little long. The answer is very easy to understand. Length is not always the deciding factor.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the list to a string literal, remove all unwanted symbol ('), and convert it back using `eval()`

```
mylist = ['{"data": {"id": "854652314"', '"value": 854652314', '"name": "854652314"}}', '{"data": {"id": "B2"', '"value": "B2"', '"name": "B2"}}', '{"data": {"id": "457856954"', '"value": 457856954', '"name": "457856954"}}']
mylist = str(mylist).replace("'", "")
mylist = eval(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
[{'data': {'id': '854652314', 'value': 854652314, 'name': '854652314'}}, {'data': {'id': 'B2', 'value': 'B2', 'name': 'B2'}}, {'data': {'id': '457856954', 'value': 457856954, 'name': '457856954'}}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach, I have formatted list..

```
import json
mylist = ['{"data": {"id": "854652314", "value": "854652314", "name": "854652314"}}', '{"data": {"id": "B2", "value": "B2", "name": "B2"}}', '{"data": {"id": "457856954", "value": "457856954", "name": "457856954"}}']
res = [json.loads(idx) for idx in mylist]
print(res)
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for you changed the input list

Comment: list data are formatted badly.. we should fix this first..

Comment: But you don't know where the data comes from, maybe that's how OP gets it and not just a mistake in copy-pasting to SO

Comment: I agree. OP needs to give a little more info on why the input list looks like that.

Comment: He is just a beginner, we should have some common sense that data should be in a proper way..

Comment: Where does it say he is a beginner?

Comment: You don't get to change the parameters of the question. If he says "I have a list like this", that's what you have to work with, unless they say they can change the input.

Comment: Yeah but you guys don't have a sense I think then fine..

Comment: Maybe you're right and OP will be happy with your answer if they change their question or provide more context. In the mean time you provide a working solution to a different problem